# iphone 4 wifi issues on work network

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

I'm having problems connecting the the work wifi network.

When I go to *Settings* the network name is listed under Wi-Fi

However the "network" logo in the top bar shows 3G not the signal strength.  If I look at *Settings > Wi-Fi* there is a "spinner" next to the network name.

Clicking "Forget this Network" and reselecting prompts for the password, and does not reject it - taking you back to the first situation.

I have done a hard reset, reset Network Settings, rebooted the Wi-Fi router, everything short of a reset of the phone.  I've even looked to see if the router has any blacklists set.

Other people in the office are connecting to the Wi-Fi with no problems, on the same spec iPhones, as well as laptops etc.

My iPhone has no problems joining any other networks.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd check to see if the router has any DHCP leases left available to it.

Comment: Seems to be fine in that respect - set to expire after 24 hours, and "new" devices join no problem...

Comment: Can you see if your MAC ID is being shown in the devices list against any current lease?  Also an idea of the router model might give us an idea of any software on the Router that might be interferign with the connection.

Comment: Router is a Netgear Prosafe.  Mac Adress is listed in the router as identified, speed as 0.  I can't see the list of leases on the router.  We have 3 routers all with the same name on each floor of the office.  My phone was working fine until about 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was with the Router.

Finally managed to persuade the guys here to rebuild the router and lo and behold I can connect again...